# Python, making a function

Tags: python, function, return

I'm struggling a lot with my code. Now my teacher wants me to make a function out of this and I'm really trying but I can't figure it out. 
So I need to make a function out of this and then call it again further down. Can someone please help me or give me some tips :) :)

```
opengraph = False 

while opengraph is not True:
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        name = sys.argv[1]
        g = openmap(name)
        opengraph = True
    else:
        try:
            name = raw_input('Please enter a file: ')
            g = openmap(name)
            opengraph = True
        except:
            print 'Not able to read the file you wrote, try another time.'
origdest = raw_input('Enter origin and destination (quit to exit): ')
```

Comment: Read the "functions" section of any tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of references, on the internet, on how you can do this. Like this [one](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Functions), or this [one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm), or this [one](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/functions.html).

Anyways.. you need to use `def`, give it a name and its input parameters, like this:

```
def MyFunction(input1, input2):
   # <Rest of the code here>
```

Don't forget identation and if you are expecting your function to return something you need to insert a:

```
return output1, output2, output3
```

in the end.

Once you function is defined, you just need to call it in your main code and pass the correct input arguments if there is any.

```
output1, output2, output3 = MyFunction(input1, input2)
```

Comment: Good explanation Eduardo!

Comment: Yeah I understand the basics of functions and "how" to write them, but I just got stuck on my code with the inputs and outputs. The program either doesn't work or errors come up when I try different methods

Comment: Ah it worked now, had spaced one line more than I should have! Thank you so much for your help and time Eduardo :D You are very very kind :)

Comment: @needhelp Instead of using `rawinput` to get name and origdest you could use them as inputs for your function. I think this is probably what your professor wants. Then, in your main code you can use  `rawinput` to get these parameters from the user and invoke the function you created passing them as input.
If that's the case, please, accept the anwser

Comment: I'll ask my professor, but you again so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this link to this tutorial helps, functions must be defined and then called to execute. In Python, functions syntactically look like this...

```
def nameOfFunction (parameters):
    code to perform task/tasks...

# Call your function...
nameOfFunction(parameter)
```

Follow this link to go to the tutorial and good luck! [Link to tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm)

Comment: According to the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names) the example for the function name should be `name_of _function`.

Comment: While the guide may say that, I see nothing wrong with using CamelCasing for declaring names of functions, but to each their own I suppose.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and time! :)